# Oxidized Avocado: What's Going on & How to Prevent It

Tags: storage-method, avocados

So what exactly happens to the flavor of avocados when it oxidizes? I made some guacamole and as many are familiar, it forms that yucky garbage-green color.

Now, it tastes different. I'm not sure if it's necessarily *bad* though. Maybe it's just an acquired taste. The essence is still kinda there and I feel bad scraping that first 1/8 inch off and just chucking it away. I can't tell if it tastes spoiled because it looks that way, or if it's just undergone a really crappy reconstitution of it's flavors and there's been a quantifiable decrease in yumminess.

Side note: a friend taught me to cover the top layer of guac with sour cream. This works awesome. I just didn't have any on hand for my last batch.